# SharePoint Central administration URL using JavaScript

Tags: sharepoint

How to get SharePoint Central administration URL using JavaScript ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This cannot be done using JavaScript.

Unfortunately the objects that are required to perform this operation (i.e. SPFarm, SPWebService, SPWebApplication...etc) are not exposed through Client Object Model.

Note : **Client Object Model does not provide access above the Site Collection level.**

Comment: Please refer this link for limitations of SharePoint Web Services - https://www.codeproject.com/articles/63861/limitations-of-sharepoint-web-services